# Ordering issue when using SQL variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I run this query:

```
SELECT stockcarddetail.id, stockcarddetail.date, stockcarddetail.quantity, stockcarddetail.pricePerItem
  FROM Stockcard
  LEFT JOIN staff
         ON staff.branchId = stockcard.branchId
  LEFT JOIN stockcarddetail
         ON stockcarddetail.stockcardId = stockcard.id
 WHERE staff.username = 'jemmy.h'
   AND stockcarddetail.quantity > 0
   AND stockcard.productId = '98924a5f-6afb-11e7-8dd4-2c56dcbcb038'
 ORDER BY date ASC
```

and get the result below:

```
id | date       | quantity| pricePerItem
50 | 2017-10-15 | 10.00   | 10000.00
1  | 2017-10-18 | 20.00   | 10000.00
```

Then, I need to calculate the cumulative of quantity based on the order above, so I run this query:

```
SELECT a.*, @tot:=@tot + a.quantity FROM
(SELECT @tot:= 0)b
JOIN
(SELECT stockcarddetail.id, stockcarddetail.date, stockcarddetail.quantity, stockcarddetail.pricePerItem
FROM Stockcard
LEFT JOIN staff
       ON staff.branchId = stockcard.branchId
LEFT JOIN stockcarddetail
       ON stockcarddetail.stockcardId = stockcard.id
WHERE staff.username = 'jemmy.h'
  AND stockcarddetail.quantity > 0
  AND stockcard.productId = '98924a5f-6afb-11e7-8dd4-2c56dcbcb038'
ORDER BY date ASC) a
```

Then I got this result:

```
id | date       | quantity| pricePerItem | @tot
1  | 2017-10-18 | 20.00   | 10000.00     | 20
50 | 2017-10-15 | 10.00   | 10000.00     | 30
```

However, the result that I want is like this:

```
id | date       | quantity| pricePerItem | @tot
50 | 2017-10-15 | 10.00   | 10000.00     | 10
1  | 2017-10-18 | 20.00   | 10000.00     | 30
```

How can I get the expected result?

**EDIT**

Simplified version of the problem can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ad91/3

Comment: If you really want LEFT JOIN, move the right side table conditions from WHERE to ON. As it is now you get regular inner join result.

Comment: As per my understanding of your code, you will never get output `10,20`, It can either be `20,30` or `10,30`

Comment: @Ravi My bad, I mean 10,30

Comment: Have you tried moving the "ORDER BY" out of the subquery? So do "ORDER BY a.date ASC" after the subquery @Bla...

Comment: Yes, but it will re-order the result such that the `@tot` become `30, 20`.

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Do you want the total to be the total of all rows prior to the row you're selecting?

Comment: The expected result shown above is the one that I want.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from you, you want the cumulative total for each entry.

I suggest ditching the variable and relying on a subquery instead:

```
SELECT  
scd.id,  
scd.date,  
scd.quantity,  
scd.pricePerItem, 
(SELECT SUM(scd1.quantity) FROM StockcardDetail AS scd1 WHERE scd1.stockcardId = scd.stockcardId AND scd1.date <= scd.date) AS total 
FROM Stockcard 
LEFT JOIN staff ON staff.branchId = stockcard.branchId 
LEFT JOIN stockcarddetail AS scd ON scd.stockcardId = stockcard.id

WHERE staff.username = 'jemmy.h'  
AND scd.quantity > 0  
AND stockcard.productId = '98924a5f-6afb-11e7-8dd4-2c56dcbcb038' 
ORDER BY scd.date ASC
```

The idea behind this is to make it select the sum of all entries prior (including the current one) for each entry.

Comment: It works, but I edit the subquery to make it more simple.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you should get the expected output from your query. But, you aren't getting your expected output, then other possible solution is (WITHOUT `JOIN`)

```
SET @tot:= 0;

SELECT 
stockcarddetail.id, 
stockcarddetail.date, 
stockcarddetail.quantity, 
stockcarddetail.pricePerItem, 
@tot:=@tot + stockcarddetail.quantity as Total
FROM Stockcard
LEFT JOIN staff ON staff.branchId = stockcard.branchId
LEFT JOIN stockcarddetail ON stockcarddetail.stockcardId = stockcard.id
WHERE staff.username = 'jemmy.h' AND stockcarddetail.quantity > 0 AND stockcard.productId = '98924a5f-6afb-11e7-8dd4-2c56dcbcb038'
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Doesn't work, in phpmyadmin it just shows `@tot:= 0`. So, I believe to be able to access the variable, we need to use `JOIN`.

Comment: @Bla... change `SELECT @tot:=0` to `SET @tot:=0`

Comment: Weirdly, I got  `30, 20` instead, with quantity in `10, 20` order.

Comment: @Bla... There is no way. Are you sure?? whether your rows are getting ordered ?

Comment: @Bla... I have shared demo link, you can try also. It is working as expected. If your rows are getting sorted then, how can it be possible ?

Comment: Hmm.. I agree with you.. But I don't know why it doesn't work. Luckily @Magisch answer works for me.

Comment: But, he/she used date in the WHERE clause. Check it out.

Comment: @Bla... I missed that.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ad91/3
The weird problem comes when you use `LEFT JOIN`, try changing `ASC` to `DESC`.